# How do I verify the authenticity of a linux system executable?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, checksum

I'm aware of md5sum and gpg but I have no idea if there are recorded checksums for whatever current version of ubuntu is installed.

Do these get recorded somewhere?   Specifically I'm suspicious that my /bin/ps executable has been compromised by a hacker.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most Linux distributions are based on a binary package format. In this case, find out what package a program came in, and either just reinstall it, or download the package and compare.

`ps` is part of *procps*, and its Ubuntu packages [available here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/procps). `ps` has the MD5 checksum `d9a2e1562e6aabb8f02b43f8b6e3d7eb` in its current release for "Raring Ringtail" for amd64.

Answer (score 4):

Most package systems have a way to check the integrity of installed packages.

For RPM based systems  : `rpm -V <packagename>`

For Debian / Ubuntu you can use [debsums](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/debsums.1.html) :

> debsums - check the MD5 sums of installed Debian packages

This is mostly useful to find accidental corruptions. If you suspect malicious modification, tools like [rkhunter](http://rkhunter.sourceforge.net/) or [chkrootkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chkrootkit) may be useful.

Don't forget that once a system has been compromised you can't trust it any more.

Comment: +1, also: "you can't trust it any more" includes any positive verification results of system binaries performed on this system.

Comment: Good point.  Dynamic libs could be tinkered with and then md5sum would not show anything.  We ended up wiping the system because the break-in appeared to be a pretty sophisticated attack.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if there is a list of md5 hashes...

However, you can always recompile `ps` from source and compare the md5 hashes of both.

Comment: As far as I know, the md5 will with a very high likely hood differ due to differences between the systems (different versions of gcc/g++, different configurations, possible difference in patch levels of the sources etc.). In theory it is a good idea, in practice it is easier to use the package manager to verify the integrity.

Comment: oh yeah... good point, didnt think about that